# Want to create API for my android application done using Intel XDK

Tags: android, api, intel

Want to create API for my android application done using Intel XDK (if you have dreamfactory in suggest list) tell me how to import my website database to dreamfactory and use it as api for proper working of my dynamic app ??

Comment: I didn't tried anything ! I'm new to this platform so chosed dreamfactory as backend ! but don't know how to import my existing data to dreamfactory and convert into an API

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so here you go.

Take a look at this intro by intel:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/integrating-apis-with-xdk-hotwire-sample-app

It's basically jquery.

In your case, your db call would look like this :

```
$.get("https://yourdsp/rest/db/:table").then(function(result){
//do something with result
}
```